# JS variable conversion failed - using AJAX to get the time from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to get the time new zealand time using jQuery AJAX but no luck.

How can I do this exactly as desired?

time.php:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set ('Etc/GMT+12');
echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O');?>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    var today
    $.get('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/time.php', function(data) 
    {
        var today = new Date(data);
        var d = new Date(today);
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] =  "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        var cDay = weekday[d.getDay()];
        var cHour = d.getHours();
        var cMin = d.getMinutes();
        console.log(cDay+ " " +cHour+":"+cMin);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is time.php returning? is the issue with ajax or with the callback?

Comment: Seems like you're using PHP code in the get() method. This should probably be a URL to time.php. See the jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: @PseudoOne Presumably the php function returns the URL

Comment: Use `date('r')` to get the proper formatting instead of that gangly version. Also, the gangly version you have is missing the comma after the weekday.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you can view network transactions in the Developer Tools "Network" tab.  You can see exactly what your .get call is returning and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: @Anthony: Tue May 20 2014 13:48:58 -1200

Comment: @Jed I thought you said you weren't able to get the date from the PHP script?

Comment: @Jed it looks like you're formatting the time on both ends (PHP and jQuery), you should just output the unix timestamp (`time()`) with PHP and format that using jQuery on the other end.

Comment: Ah, true. I didn't see a file name so I assumed HTML. Is there a missing equal sign in the declaration?

Comment: I just renamed the title. You can suggest to edit it if its not appropriate. The desired output here is to output new zealand time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the timezone like so in PHP as far as I know. You must procede with their friendly names that you can find here http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

I strongly suggest (as said in comments) that you use the `date` function to format your string as desired.

This will work fine :

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set ('Pacific/Auckland');
echo date('l H:i');?>
```

This way you won't need more than that JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    var today
    $.get('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/time.php', function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Any link how can I execute your suggestion on your last sentence?

Comment: I added an even easier solution. Hope this helps. If you need more detailed information about the date, then you could return json from the server like so :
`echo json_encode(array('weekday' => date('l'),'hour'=> date('H')));`

In your JS, simply use `data = $.parseJSON(data);` and your vars will be available under data.weekday, data.hour, and so on.

Comment: Wow. That's a lot easier. Thanks a lot!